# log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j --- after adding graphql dependency to pom

Tags: java, spring, graphql, log4j

Im trying mess around with graph ql and integrating it with our existing project.  Im following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql) since our project is java with spring framework

but after adding the dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and trying to start my project i get an error

> Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: log4j-slf4j-impl
> cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j

I have found similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629214/caused-by-org-apache-logging-log4j-loggingexception-log4j-slf4j-impl-cannot-be), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891737/getting-exception-org-apache-logging-slf4j-slf4jloggercontext-cannot-be-cast-to)
Which lead me to attempt to add exclusions but that did NOT help

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j-slf4j-impl</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j-to-slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Excluded dependencies *groupId* seems wrong. Changing excluded *groupId*'s to *org.apache.logging.log4j* may solve your problem.